# how to implement PAYEER payment integration in angular 4

Tags: angular

how to implement `payeer` payment integration in angular 4 application ?
i want following details

- Get balance
- windrow and deposit
- transaction history
- authentication
- information about transaction

Comment: are you tried some code?

Comment: currently not implement any code but i finding some npm package for payeer with angular 4